Android studio crash in Mac os version 14.4.1
I am a Flutter developer and have recently downloaded the latest version of Android Studio, Jellyfish, on my Mac running macOS Sonoma 14.4.1. My Mac is a late 2013 model, and I used Legacy Core Patcher to successfully install the OS, which is functioning well overall. However, I am facing two issues: Android Studio crashes when I run the Android emulator, and I am unable to select the iOS simulator.
If anyone has encountered these issues or knows how to resolve them on an unsupported Mac, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Find the studio.vmoptions file in the specified path, you can also check the following locations:
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions

or
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2024.1/studio.vmoptions

add these two lines and save them now you are good to start your emulator
-Dsun.java2d.metal=false
-Xmx2048m

